# firefox says `this.view` is undefined, but its clearly defined when dumping object in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

[image: http://puu.sh/jMqbJ/f035efa2da.png]

I read an article on building singletons based by creating them, then overwriting their constructors and always returning the first created instance. this works fine, however one of my methods can't reference its properties:

```
//fetch a view and render it with the supplied args, then perform a callback.
jqMVC.prototype.render = function(template,args,callback){
    twig({
        href: this.view_path+template,
        load: function(template) { 
            var html = template.render(args);
            this.view.html(html).promise().done(function(){
                if(typeof callback === "function"){
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

As you can see in the image though, view is clearly defined, and even has a default value if the programmer did not overwrite it. view is a jquery object. how can i use it in my method?

Comment: "Overwriting their constructors". This sounds scary xD. Can you show the code for how you are building your singletons please?

Comment: yeah, i'm gonna post the full code because apparently i'm too dumb to understand javascript. this language is insane from my point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is inside the `twig` callback `this` may not be referring to the `jqMVC` object.

You can use a closure variable as given below

```
jqMVC.prototype.render = function (template, args, callback) {
    var self = this;
    twig({
        href: this.view_path + template,
        load: function (template) {
            var html = template.render(args);
            self.view.html(html).promise().done(function () {
                if (typeof callback === "function") {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```